# How to delete telemetry and attributes of entities when entities themselves are deleted

Tags: thingsboard

I didn't find any information in the official documentation about whether the telemetry and properties are deleted after the device is deleted.
However, when I check the database after deleting the device, the telemetry and attributes of the deleted device are still present and have not been deleted.

I want ThingsBoard to remove both the telemetry and the attribute values of this device when the device is deleted

ThingsBoard version : 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can either delete the device attributes/telemetries via Database query or Administration REST API. I would recommend the second option:

https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/

e.g. there is in an endpoint for deleting device attributes:

*<TB_HOST_URL>/swagger-ui/#/telemetry-controller/deleteDeviceAttributesUsingDELETE*

[image]